# Department values are not showing up in people search results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, user-profile-service, people-search

We have Directory Sync setup in our environment. All of the users and corresponding user profile attributes are provisioned directly from our local AD. However, when searching through the OOTB People Search page, neither search results nor the search refiner shows people's department. The only two properties I can see here are Job Title and Keywords...

1. Checked the User Profiles service (People -> Manage User Profiles) in the SharePoint admin center. All of the users have the correct properties and values synced from our local AD
2. Checked the Search Schema for Managed Properties. Department property is mapped with"People:Department" and "ows_Department". Department property is Queryable, Retrievable, and Refinable
3. Called the SharePoint REST API to retrieve current user's properties. I can see the correct properties and values on my JSON result

Did I miss something here? Any help or guidance would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you say OOTB people search page, are you talking about my sites?  Or searching in people picker?  People picker does a query against AD itself does not rely upon the User Profile Service for this information.  If you are talking about my sites search, is the user profile service application one of the service applications connected to the web app hosting my sites?

Comment: It's the people search people search page in an Enterprise Search Center: https://<Your Tenant URL>/search/Pages/peopleresults.aspx

Comment: Oh this is SharePoint Online?  Sorry, I missed that part.  I only use on-prem.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the PeopleResults page and edit the Refinement web part, do you have the Department managed property in the list of refiners? If not add it back.

Comment: Yes, I checked the refiner webpart, it has the Department managed property. I am suspecting I need to do a re-index/re-crawling for my user profiles. But I know this couldn't be done in SharePoint Online, Any suggestion here?

Comment: You can wait a week, I think the Profiles are crawled weekly, or file a SR and have Microsoft fix it.